# Only display expression language value once

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

I got a boostrap error/success message that is being diplayed on index.jsp via expression language.
${ output }

The content is generated during the login.
I want the message to be shown only right after the login, so only the first time the index.jsp is accessed after the login.

In order to achieve that, I tried to set the value of ${ output } out after being displayed, so that it doesn't get displayed as long as a new value is set.

I have tried these two ways after ${ output }:

```
<c:set var = "output" value=""/>
${output = ""}
```

Neither of them works.
What would you do?

Comment: Please read https://stackoverflow.com/tags/el/info

Comment: The answer depends on how exactly the value is being set. But this information is nowhere visible in the question.